# Thunderbird 91.7.0 keeps freezing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: freeze, thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird as my main e-mail and calendar app in Ubuntu for many years. Currently running Thunderbird 91.8, Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36.8.

For a few months now Thunderbird freezes very often. For about one minute all windows of Thunderbird become unresponsive.
If I click on them many times, I get the default Ubuntu dialog, that this app has become unresponsive and I can choose to kill it or wait. If I wait, it usually becomes responsive again after one minute. This may happen again and again in one or two minute intervals so the usage is very difficult.

I have tried, with no success:

- safe mode (disabling all add-ons)
- disabling the global indexer
- disabling the calendars.
- disabling the hardware acceleration
- upgrading Thunderbird from version 91.7 to 91.8.0

In order to get some debugging:

- I enabled the development console,
- I run from the commandline, so that errors are displayed there
- I even checked the system messages log.

I couldn't find any obvious error message that correlates with the problem. Any help or directions on what to try, or how to debug would be helpful.